# how to update angular ui.router nested state immediately?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I tried to make modal popup with angularjs, webpack2.

But some problems are bothering me..

I want to make modal popup that has custom url but

in modal popup, `$state.current` still indicates parent's state.

---

I searched `onEnter` function is invoked **when state transition is done completely.**

and meantime, modal's state is not updated. (I think this is the reason why modal's state indicates parent's state)

I can get modal's own state and stateParams with setTimeout function but it is just trick right ?

How can I get modal's state with the right way?

===

this is my app.js,

```
  // HOME
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'client/pages/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
  })

  // PLAYER MODAL
  .state('player', {
    url: 'player/:playerName',
    parent: 'home',
    onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
      $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'client/pages/player/player.html',
        resolve: {},
        controller: 'PlayerController'
      }).result.then(function (result) {
        // $scope.$close
        alert('result ->' + result);
      }, function (result) {
        // $scope.$dismiss
        alert('dismiss ->' + result);
      }).finally(function () {
        // handle finally
        return $state.go('home');
      });
    }
  });
```

HomeController,

```
  angular.module('907degree')
  .controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.state =  $state.current;
    $scope.players = ['messi', 'hazard', 'ronaldo'];

    $scope.showModal = function (playerId) {
      $state.go('player', { playerName: playerId });
    };
})
```

and PlayerController.

```
  angular.module('907degree')
  .controller('PlayerController', ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, itemService) => {
    $scope.playerState = $state.current;
    $scope.params = $stateParams.playerName;
    $scope.item = itemService.get($stateParams.id);

    $scope.ok = function () {
      $scope.$close('clicked OK');
    };

    $scope.dismiss = function () {
      $scope.$dismiss('clicked CANCEL');
    };

    $scope.checkState = function () {
      console.log($state.current, $stateParams);
      console.log($scope.playerName);
    }
  })
```

I think my repo is better than plunker to solve this problem.. so here is it.

git clone hagfish1210@gitlab.com/hagfish1210/907degrees.git & npm install & npm run dev

Comment: I think my repo is better than plunker to solve this problem.. so here is it.
git clone https://hagfish1210@gitlab.com/hagfish1210/907degrees.git

& npm install

& npm run dev

Comment: If you are using ui-router 1.0, the easy answer is to inject the `$transition$` and get the to/from state and to/from parameters from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the current `$transition$`.

```
onEnter: function($transition$, $state, $uibModal) {
  $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'client/pages/player/player.html',
    resolve: { $transition$: () => $transition$ },
    controller: 'PlayerController'
  }).result.then(function (result) {
    // $scope.$close
    alert('result ->' + result);
  }, function (result) {
    // $scope.$dismiss
    alert('dismiss ->' + result);
  }).finally(function () {
    // handle finally
    return $state.go('home');
  });
}
```

In PlayerController ask the transition for its parameters

```
angular.module('907degree')
  .controller('PlayerController', ($scope, $http, $state, $transition$, itemService) => {
    $scope.playerState = $state.current;
    var params = $transition$.params();
    $scope.params = params.playerName;
    $scope.item = itemService.get(params.id);

    $scope.ok = function () {
      $scope.$close('clicked OK');
    };

    $scope.dismiss = function () {
      $scope.$dismiss('clicked CANCEL');
    };

    $scope.checkState = function () {
      console.log($state.current, params);
      console.log($scope.playerName);
    }
  })
```

The `Transition` class exposes much information about the running transition: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#params

Comment: inject $transition$ to player controller also right? you are my savior. thank you so much Chris!